# Elastic search: find word parts in nested object

Tags: elasticsearch, nested

I'm not able to find parts of a word in a nested object. Only the full word is found. My analyzer configuration is as follows:

```
{
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 1,
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "word_part_filter": {
          "type": "ngram",
          "min_gram": 3,
          "max_gram": 15
        },
        "word_part_front_filter": {
          "type": "edgeNGram",
          "min_gram": 2,
          "max_gram": 15
        },
        "codeid_filter": {
          "type": "pattern_replace",
          "pattern": "[-/.:]",
          "replacement": "",
          "preserve_original": true
        }
      },
      "char_filter": {
        "umlaut_char_filter": {
          "type": "mapping",
          "mappings": [
            "Ã¶=>oe",
            "Ã¤=>ae",
            "Ã¼=>ue",
            "Ã?=>ss",
            "Ã?=>Oe",
            "Ã?=>Ae",
            "Ã?=>Ue"
          ]
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "description_analyser_query": {
          "type": "custom",
          "char_filter": [
            "html_strip"
          ],
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "stop",
            "asciifolding"
          ]
        },
        "description_analyser_idx": {
          "type": "custom",
          "char_filter": [
            "html_strip"
          ],
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "stop",
            "asciifolding",
            "word_part_filter"
          ]
        },
        "name_analyser_query": {
          "type": "custom",
          "char_filter": [
            "umlaut_char_filter"
          ],
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "asciifolding"
          ]
        },
        "name_analyser_idx": {
          "type": "custom",
          "char_filter": [
            "umlaut_char_filter"
          ],
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "asciifolding",
            "word_part_filter"
          ]
        },
        "codeid_analyser_query": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "keyword",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "codeid_filter"
          ]
        },
        "codeid_analyser_idx_front": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "keyword",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "codeid_filter",
            "word_part_front_filter"
          ]
        },
        "codeid_analyser_idx_any": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "keyword",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "codeid_filter",
            "word_part_filter"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is the nested object mapping (extracted):

```
{
  "properties": {    
    "aid": {
      "type": "nested",
      "properties": {
        "tpid": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "codeid_analyser_idx_any"
        },
        "aid": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "codeid_analyser_idx_any"
        }
      }    
    }
  }
}
```

I'm searching with this query (extract). Only the "nested" part is essential here:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "nested": {
                  "path": "aid",
                  "query": {
                    "bool": {
                      "must": {
                        "match": {
                          "aid.aid": {
                            "query": "1200",
                            "analyzer": "codeid_analyser_query"
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      "filter": {
                        "or": [
                          {
                            "match": {
                              "aid.tpid": "buyer_specific"
                            }
                          },
                          {
                            "match": {
                              "aid.tpid": "mytpid"
                            }
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ],
            "minimum_should_match": 1
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

there is an element with aid=120000008

When using the analyzers in the fields, it finds nothing. When using no analyzers at all in the nested object mapping and query, only full words (like "120000008") will be found, but not "1200". Any ideas?

Comment: For the "1200" part, isn't it because in your query you use "must" "match"? In that case, the string must match (obviously), and 1200 and 1200000008 are definitely not a match

Comment: The "must" part refers to the match itself. When I understood it correctly, then must the query match, but how matching is done is defined in "match".

Comment: Could you provide an extract of documents you have in your index?

Comment: Are there no ideas here?

Comment: I've just recreated your setup on a ES 2 cluster and it works perfectly for me. Not sure what's going wrong for you. Can you show the exact output you get from `curl -XGET localhost:9200/your_index` ?

Comment: Note that I've created a sample document like this: `{
  "aid": {
    "aid": "120000008",
    "tpid": "mytpid"
  }
}` and I'm able to retrieve it with your exact query.

Comment: And you're just searching for 1200?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, using ElasticSearch 5.2, using an index called test, and applying the mapping on a type called "product" (rewriting only the filter part so it is compliant to the evolution of the querying language), I obtain the correct result. The query:

```
GET test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "nested": {
                  "path": "aid",
                  "query": {
                    "bool": {
                      "must": {
                        "match": {
                          "aid.aid": {
                            "query": "1200",
                            "analyzer": "codeid_analyser_query"
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      "filter": {
                        "terms": {
                          "aid.tpid": [
                            "mytpid",
                            "buyer_specific"
                          ]
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ],
            "minimum_should_match": 1
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The index:

```
GET test/_search

{
  "took": 8,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "product",
        "_id": "AVrJ1CSd-NyeQ4r64kP6",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "aid": {
            "aid": "120000008",
            "tpid": "mytpid"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The analyzer (I removed the umlaut filter as it was unreadable on my computer, and it does not change the result as in the tests it is not used):

```
PUT test
{
  "settings": {
     "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "word_part_filter": {
          "type": "ngram",
          "min_gram": 3,
          "max_gram": 15
        },
        "word_part_front_filter": {
          "type": "edgeNGram",
          "min_gram": 2,
          "max_gram": 15
        },
        "codeid_filter": {
          "type": "pattern_replace",
          "pattern": "[-/.:]",
          "replacement": "",
          "preserve_original": true
        }
      },

      "analyzer": {
        "description_analyser_query": {
          "type": "custom",
          "char_filter": [
            "html_strip"
          ],
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "stop",
            "asciifolding"
          ]
        },
        "description_analyser_idx": {
          "type": "custom",
          "char_filter": [
            "html_strip"
          ],
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "stop",
            "asciifolding",
            "word_part_filter"
          ]
        },

        "codeid_analyser_query": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "keyword",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "codeid_filter"
          ]
        },
        "codeid_analyser_idx_front": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "keyword",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "codeid_filter",
            "word_part_front_filter"
          ]
        },
        "codeid_analyser_idx_any": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "keyword",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "codeid_filter",
            "word_part_filter"
          ]
        }
      }
     }
  }
}
```

The mapping on product:

```
PUT test/_mapping/product
{

  "properties": {    
    "aid": {
      "type": "nested",
      "properties": {
        "tpid": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "codeid_analyser_idx_any"
        },
        "aid": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "codeid_analyser_idx_any"
        }
      }    
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it works...worked. I don't know. The solution was there. I configured it correctly, but at the time, the result was wrong. Thx.